# How to acess form details in php page using html 'id' attribute

Tags: php

i have a form having employeeNo,name and a submit button. when the form is submitted it redirects to a php page, Now the problem is i want to access the values of the form by using 'id' attribute?if possible i need the html and php code.

Is there a way to solve this Problem?

```
enter code here<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test.php" method="">
        <input type="text" name='employeeNo' id="input1">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name='name' id="input2">
        <br>
        <input type="submit"  id="input3">
    </form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I need to acess the form values using id='input1' ,id='input2'  in php SOME HOW?

Comment: Only the `name` attribute is sent to PHP, not the `id`

Answer (score 1):

In your `test.php` file you need to retrieve the values. Since you don't define any method in your form, by default it should be "GET"

Your php file could look like the following:

```
<?php

$employee_no = $_GET['employeeNo'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

I would suggest defining your form method as POST though, like the following:

```
...
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
...
```

so your php file will retrieve values from form like this:

```
<?php

$employee_no = $_POST['employeeNo'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

You may also look at this for further explanation:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: please don't send people to w3 schools for php help  (it's ok for client-side languages). While much of it is accurate, there is a lot of out of date and dangerous information given on that page and can encourage very bad habits

Comment: True, what would you recommend instead?